# AWS Cross Account

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I've got 2 AWS accounts.

AccountA:

- LambdaA assumes RoleB created in AccountB
- LambdaA tries to create a DynamoDB table in AccountB

AccountB:

- RoleB is setup to allow AccountA to have full access to DynamoDB

LambdaA assumed role smoothly.
But DynamoDB table was created in AccountA.

From syntax, how do you specify that DynamoDB table should be created in AccountB?

```
exports.handler= function(event, context, callback) {
  assumeRole(function(err, res) {
    if(err) { context.fail("ASSUME_ROLE::" + err.toString()); return; }
    createTable(function(err, res) {
      if(err) { context.fail("CREATE_TABLE::" + err.toString()); return; }
    });
  });
}

var assumeRole= function(callback) {
  var params= {
    RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::123:role/Role",
    RoleSessionName: "role",
    ExternalId: "role"
  };
  sts.assumeRole(params, function(err, res) {
    err ? callback(err) : callback(null, res);
  });
}

var createTable= function(callback) {
  var params= {
    TableName: "TEST",
    KeySchema: [
      { AttributeName: "test", KeyType: "HASH"}
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
      { AttributeName: "test", AttributeType: "S" },
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
      ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
      WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
  }
  dynamo.createTable(params, function(err, res) {
    err ? callback(err) : callback(null, res);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you please show where you are creating `dynamo`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I have included the Lambda codes

Comment: Hahaha... ok, I need to instantiate Dynamo with credentials

Comment: Yes. You'll need to use the credentials from `AssumeRole` to create the `dynamo` client.